# Table Of Contents won't stay on the first page

Tags: table-of-contents

my question is my table of contents in my report is hell bent on staying on the second page, is there any way for me to force it to stay on the first page underneath my title and abstract? My code I'm using is given below, thank you in advance!

```
\documentclass[aps,prd,showpacs,amsmath,amssymb,bm,superscriptaddress,nofootinbib]{revtex4-1}  


\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{color}% bold math
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{listings}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\leftline{\includegraphics[scale=0.06]{Logo}\hfill PHYS Final Report}
\end{figure}

\vspace*{1.5cm}

\title{Title }
\author{Name}
\date{\today}
\begin{abstract}
\vspace*{1.0cm}
Abstract
\vspace*{1.0cm}
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using (perhaps `book` or `report`)?

Comment: It is a bit of a weird one I copied it from one of my university report templates, it is:

Comment: ```\documentclass[aps,prd,showpacs,amsmath,amssymb,bm,superscriptaddress,nofootinbib]{revtex4-1}```

Comment: the tableofcontents is defined by the documentclass so without that last comment the question would be impossible to answer, even now it would be easier if you fixed the example code so that it demonstrated the problem. Ie a complete small document with an unexpected blank page

Comment: Okay,  I have edited the original code and reproduce the error in overleaf so hopefully this code reproduces my problem, thanks!

Comment: you could delete `\leftline{\includegraphics[scale=0.06]{Logo}\hfill ` as we don't hav ethat (and adding `\section{zzz}` so the table of contents isn't enpty would possibly help

Comment: Have just tried that and for some reason it still set on staying on the second page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `revtex4-1` I get a page break but with the current `revtex4-2` class the table of contents comes on page 1.

[image]

```
\documentclass[aps,prd,showpacs,amsmath,amssymb,bm,superscriptaddress,nofootinbib]{revtex4-2}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
\end{figure}

\vspace*{1.5cm}

\title{Title }
\author{Name}
\date{\today}
\begin{abstract}
\vspace*{1.0cm}
\vspace*{1.0cm}
\end{abstract}
\maketitle



\tableofcontents

\section{zzz}
a
\section{zz zz}
b
\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks perfect, thank you very much David!